# TypeError: the first argument must be callable

Tags: python, methods, schedule

I am using python and schedule lib to create a cron-like job

```
class MyClass:

        def local(self, command):
                #return subprocess.call(command, shell=True)
                print "local"

        def sched_local(self, script_path, cron_definition):
                import schedule
                import time

                #job = self.local(script_path)

                schedule.every(1).minutes.do(self.local(script_path))

                while True:
                        schedule.run_pending()
                        time.sleep(1)
```

When calling this in a main

```
cg = MyClass()
cg.sched_local(script_path, cron_definition)
```

I got this:

```
local
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "MyClass.py", line 131, in <module>
    cg.sched_local(script_path, cron_definition)
  File "MyClass.py", line 71, in sched_local
    schedule.every(1).minutes.do(self.local(script_path))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/schedule/__init__.py", line 271, in do
    self.job_func = functools.partial(job_func, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: the first argument must be callable
```

When calling another method within the class instead of sched_local, like

```
def job(self):
    print "I am working"
```

The job works fine.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`do` expects a callable and any arguments it make take.

Therefore your call to `do` should look like:

```
schedule.every(1).minutes.do(self.local, script_path)
```

The `do` implementation can be found [here](https://github.com/dbader/schedule/blob/master/schedule/__init__.py).

```
def do(self, job_func, *args, **kwargs):
    """Specifies the job_func that should be called every time the
    job runs.

    Any additional arguments are passed on to job_func when
    the job runs.
    """
    self.job_func = functools.partial(job_func, *args, **kwargs)
    functools.update_wrapper(self.job_func, job_func)
    self._schedule_next_run()
    return self
```