# the first argument must be callable python schedule for function

Tags: python

Hi I am trying to use schedule but it returns the first argument must be callable. I tried looking into other where they say, I must not use the parentheses.
However if I do not use the parentheses how would I pass the var?

It looks like this

`schedule.every().day.at("13:42").do(scrape("www.website.com"))`

where scrape is a function define as

```
def scrape(URL):
    items = scrapeModule1(URL)
    return items
```

If I take out the URL what or how am I supposed to call out the var in the def function?

Comment: You could hardcore the URL in the function or just pass a `lambda: scrape(...)` as the function.

Comment: `do(scrape, "www.website.com")`. See [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26583557/3890632).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without any knowledge of the framework you are using or the error you get:

```
schedule.every().day.at("13:42").do(lambda : scrape("www.website.com"))
```

Comment: using beautiful soup python. it's all python modules. It works. Can I know what is lambda and what does it do exactly?

Comment: Let me Google that for you: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lambda.asp . A lambda is a callable without a name